# store tokens into array

Tags: c, arrays, string

I need to store tokens into an array. And then i want to find equal tokens in sentence.

```
int main()    
{
    int i=0;
    char* words[200];
    char text[200];

    printf("Enter one sentence \n ");
    gets(text);
    char *word = strtok(text, " ");

    while(word!=0)
    {
        words=malloc(strlen(word)+1);              
        strcpy(words[i++], word);
        printf("[%s]\n", word);
        word=strtok(NULL, " ,.!?");
    }

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

I don't know why is this erorr- 22 incompatible types in assignment of void* to char*[200]'
And if i change words to words[i]=malloc..... got error 22  invalid conversion from void* to char*'

And then i want to know how from this array i can compare these tokens with strcmp.
This is my try but looks like not working.

```
for (k=0; k<199; k++)
{
 for (j=k+1; j<200; j++)
  { 
             if (strcmp(words[k],words[j])==0) 
             {
             printf("equal words are %d",words);
             }
             else
             {
             printf("In this sentence aren't equal words");
             }
   }

}
```

Comment: I'd suggest "words[i++] = strdup(word);" instead of the malloc and strcpy.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of

```
words = malloc( strlen( word ) + 1 );
```

you need to get the proper index in `words` and allocate that.

```
words[i] = malloc( strlen( word ) + 1 );
```

---

You haven't attempted to try to compare the tokens. Once you show what you have tried (or after you make an attempt), we will help.

Comment: Now i got error- 22  invalid conversion from `void*' to `char*' .

Comment: @user2883601 May be because you are compiling with a C++ compiler? In C, `void*` is implicitly convertible to any other data pointer (no need for any casting). Hence, you shouldn't see that error (or warning) message.

Comment: @clcto I writed code to compare tokens can you help whats wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
    words=malloc(strlen(word)+1);
```

to

```
    words[i]=malloc(strlen(word)+1);
```

Currently, you are assigning the malloc'ed value to the array itself, you rather intended to assign it to an *element* of the array.

If you have strdup() (a posix function, not in standard C), then you can use it instead of malloc()+strlen() combination and less error-prone.

I also suggest to use `i++` as a separate statement to avoid any errors in the future (What you have is not wrong; just a general suggestion).

Answer (score 1):

`char * words[200]` is a 200-element array of `char *`s.

Arrays are static, so `words=malloc(strlen(word)+1);` doesn't make sense. words is an array of pointers, but `malloc` returns a `void *`.

I think what you want is to have a variable to use as an iterator - `words[i]` instead of just `words`.

If changing to `words[i] = malloc(strlen(word)+1);` gives you an invalid conversion error, you can try casting, though you shouldn't have to, since `malloc` returns a `void*`. To cast, use `words[i] = (char*) malloc(strlen(word) + 1);`. The `(char*)` tells the compiler that even though it looks like you're doing an invalid conversion, you know what you're doing.

Also, for the second part that attempts to find matching strings, I think you mean something like this for the first printf:
`printf("Equal words are %d, %d: %s\n", j, k, words[j]);`